# Dynamic partitioning by id

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

i need to create dynamic partitioning range by id of 1000,
stored procedure possible in mysql?

here it is stored procedure i tried

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE AddPartitions()
BEGIN
    DECLARE max_id INT;
    DECLARE next_partition_value INT DEFAULT 1; -- Start value for the next partition
    DECLARE partition_name VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    
    -- Get the maximum id value in the table
    SELECT MAX(id) INTO max_id FROM MyTable;
    
    -- Loop to add partitions dynamically
    WHILE next_partition_value <= max_id DO
        SET partition_name = CONCAT('p', next_partition_value);
        SET @sql = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD PARTITION (PARTITION ', partition_name, ' VALUES LESS THAN (', next_partition_value + 1000, '));');
        PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
        
        SET next_partition_value = next_partition_value + 1000; -- Adjust the partition range
    END WHILE;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Other than the unused variable `done` it looks OK to me. If it's not working, you need to add more details, like the error message.

Comment: There are numerous ways this could fail, but it's all based on speculating about your table. How many rows? What is the minimum `id`? Is the table already defined with range partitioning?